# What should the directory structure of Maven + version control look like?

Tags: git, svn, maven, version-control, structure

For instance, how do I manage trunks and branches with Maven and Git? Or Maven and SVN? Would it be:

```
trunk/src/main/java
trunk/src/main/resources
trunk/src/test/java
trunk/src/test/resources
branches/branch1/src/main/java
branches/branch1/src/main/resources
branches/branch1/src/test/java
branches/branch1/src/test/resources
```

Or what else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Maven**

For Maven, the "Standard Directory Layout" is described in the [Maven Introduction](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html). That's your Maven project. To check that into source control, you'd commit that complete directory structure to where your repository lives.

**SVN**

> In Subversion the URL identifies the location of the repository and the path inside the repository, so you organize the layout of the repository and its meaning. Normally you would have `trunk/`, `branches/` and `tags/` directories. (source: [Git - SVN Crash Course](http://git-scm.com/course/svn.html))

So then you indeed checkout `trunk` and have the `src/...` structure there, if you're working on the `trunk`. Switching to another branch would just switch your local workspace over to the `branches/branch` directory of the svn repository. Note the subtlety here: you're switching a different part of the remote SVN repository. You'd normally not have the whole root checked out on your hard drive, just the `trunk` or `branches/branch1` part of it.

**Git**

> In Git the URL is just the location of the repository, and it always contains branches and tags. One of the branches is the default (normally named master). (source: [Git - SVN Crash Course](http://git-scm.com/course/svn.html))

So with Git on the other hand, you do have the whole repository checked out on your hard drive. However, git does not store branches in a different folder relative to the root of the repository, it uses a tagging system for branches.